# Angular 8 ngIf expression based on the drop down value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a configured custom table generator using Angular, the table have drop down value and the text field value. Based on the drop down value I need to make the respective table cell should be editable.

app.component.html

```
<table border="1">
  <tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td>New Age</td></tr>
  <tr><td>John</td><td><select (change)="editAge(selectField1.value)" #selectField1>
    <option value="1">Less than 10</option>
    <option value="2">Greater than 10 and Less than 80</option>
    <option value="3">Less than 80</option>
  </select></td><td> <span  *ngIf="!expression">24</span> <span *ngIf="expression"><input type="text" /></span></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Jacky</td><td><select (change)="editAge(selectField2.value)" #selectField2>
    <option value="1">Less than 10</option>
    <option value="2">Greater than 10 and Less than 80</option>
    <option value="3">Less than 80</option>
  </select></td><td> <span  *ngIf="!expression">4</span> <span *ngIf="expression"><input type="text" /></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Roy</td><td><select (change)="editAge(selectField3.value)" #selectField3>
      <option value="1">Less than 10</option>
      <option value="2">Greater than 10 and Less than 80</option>
      <option value="3">Less than 80</option>
    </select></td><td> <span  *ngIf="!expression">34</span> <span *ngIf="expression"><input type="text" /></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';
  expression = false;
  nameBind: string;
  editAge(ee) {
    if (ee === '2') {
      this.expression = true;
    } else { this.expression = false;
}
  }
}
```

Expected o/p

I wan't to edit only the respective row Age

Current behavior

All the  Age field is editable

[Slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-guyvdn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I need to edit the cell depends on the drop down value

Comment: @Rijo you want to disable particular text box, based on dropdown value?

Comment: Yes bro correct

Comment: So you can use `[disabled]="selectField[1,2,3].value == 2"` based on the selected value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will handle this case as below:

I will remove `<span>` tag and use value attribute to set the value for textbox itself and use change method to detect the changed value:

HTML Code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>New Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td><select (change)="editAge(selectField1.value)" #selectField1>
    <option value="1">Less than 10</option>
    <option value="2">Greater than 10 and Less than 80</option>
    <option value="3">Less than 80</option>
  </select></td>

        <td><input value="24" [disabled]="selectField1.value == 2" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jacky</td>
        <td><select (change)="editAge(selectField2.value)" #selectField2>
    <option value="1">Less than 10</option>
    <option value="2">Greater than 10 and Less than 80</option>
    <option value="3">Less than 80</option>
  </select></td>
        <td> <input value="4" [disabled]="selectField2.value == 2" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Roy</td>
        <td><select (change)="editAge(selectField3.value)" #selectField3>
      <option value="1">Less than 10</option>
      <option value="2">Greater than 10 and Less than 80</option>
      <option value="3">Less than 80</option>
    </select></td>
        <td><input value="34" [disabled]="selectField3.value == 2" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

TS Code:

```
editAge() {
  // do nothing
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbfvtm)

Comment: Thanks its working!, Can we do this implementation using @Viewchild()

Comment: @Rijo Yes, but I don't think its needed, if you have some requirements then might be look forward

Comment: if `selectField3.value == 2` then i need to change the input text field value based on some logic. How to get the respective input field for populating that value?

Comment: You can define 3 variable in the TS like `selectFeild1Text : any` and `selectFeild2Text : any` and Just replace that `value` with `[value]="selectFeild1Text"`

Comment: If it is 100 row, its not a good way to define the 100 variables right?

Comment: @Rijo Nope, then it is now convinient to use `@ViewChild` also